# EXC_BREAKPOINT when add value on 2 dimension arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use a 2 dimension array with below code :

```
var table: [[Int]] = []

table[0].append(contentsOf: 10...15)
```

but get error :
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18f6dd21c).

Don't know what to try

Answer (score 0):

`table[0]` doesn't exist.

```swift
let range = 10...15
if table.isEmpty {
  table = [.init(range)]
} else {
  table[0].append(contentsOf: range)
}
```

Or, initialize it with an element.

```swift
var table: [[Int]] = [[]]
```